# CodeModel - How to define annotations with an enum value?

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation, sun-codemodel

It seems that the java code generator framework **CodeModel** is not capable of creating annotations which only contain an enum value **without a name** - unfortunately a very common pattern (which JPA uses, for example):

```
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date createDate;
```

The [API documentation only states](http://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/JAnnotationUse.html) *"TODO How to add enums to the annotations"*

**Question:**
Is there any way of working around this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation parameters "without a name" are actually just a shorthand for a default parameter named "value", so these are equivalent:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)

@Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this shorthand - thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that comment is out of date. There is a method `param(String name, Enum<?> value)` on `JAnnotationUse` which works fine.

**Edit:** The code would look like the following:

```
field.annotate(Temporal.class).param("value", TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

Please note that

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

Is just a short for of writing

```
@Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

This short form can be used when the annotation only contains a single parameter.

Comment: But what if I must not specify a name (as stated in the question and its example?)